# TSQL Query to fetch row details from a table when the value of a column last changed

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have two tables.

Table 1

```
   Item
    1
    2
```

Table 2

```
   Item   Date    Amount
    1     12/31     30
    1     12/30     30
    1     12/29     20
    2     12/31     100
    2     12/30     90
    2     12/29     90
```

Now my result should have

```
   Item   Date    Amount
    1    12/29     20
    2    12/30     90 
    3    12/31     12
```

Basically, i am trying to find out the date when the price changed recently. In turn, i will use this information to calculate the no of days the item is at the current price.

Thanks

Comment: You asked a similar question a day before. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4583488/tsql-query-to-fetch-row-details-of-a-table-having-the-maximum-value-for-a-column/4583518#4583518

Comment: @Cybernate: Similar, but not the same. This time he's not after the maximum value - he's after the date of the second most recent value, igonring duplicated values.

Comment: What database engine are you using?, and what version?

Comment: Too bad TSQL doesn't yet support LEAD/LAG analytic functions...

Comment: @OMG - No sign of these yet in SQL Server 2011 despite an excellent campaign by [Itzik Ben-Gan](http://www.insidetsql.com/OVER_Clause_and_Ordered_Calculations.doc) People [please vote for this here](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/254388/over-clause-enhancement-request-lag-and-lead-functions)

Comment: @Martin: There's lots of analytic functions SQL Server needs to implement.  Shame to hear they won't be implemented in 2011 :/

Answer (score 1):

```
;WITH cte
     AS (SELECT *,
                Row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY Item ORDER BY Date) -
                Row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY Amount, Amount ORDER BY Date) AS
                grp
         FROM   table2)
SELECT Item,
       MAX(Amount) AS Amount,
       MIN(Date)   AS startrange,
       MAX(Date)   AS endrange,
       1+DATEDIFF(DAY,MIN(Date),MAX(Date)) AS numdays
FROM   cte
GROUP  BY grp,
          Item
```

Returns the following for your test data

```
Item        Amount      startrange endrange   numdays
----------- ----------- ---------- ---------- -----------
1           20          2010-12-29 2010-12-29 1
1           30          2010-12-30 2010-12-31 2
2           90          2010-12-29 2010-12-30 2
2           100         2010-12-31 2010-12-31 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT Item, Date, Amount
FROM
(
    SELECT
        T2.Item,
        T2.Date,
        T2.Amount,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY T2.Item ORDER BY T2.Date DESC) rn
    FROM table2 T2
    JOIN
    (
        SELECT Item, Amount
        FROM
        (
            SELECT
                Item,
                Amount,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Item ORDER BY Date DESC) rn
            FROM table2
        ) T1
        WHERE rn = 1
    ) T3
    ON T2.Item = T3.Item AND T2.Amount <> T3.Amount
) T4
WHERE rn = 1
```

Result for your example data:

```
Item  Date        Amount
1     2010-12-29  20    
2     2010-12-30  90
```

**Explanation**

The subquery T3 finds the most recent price for each item by using ROW_NUMBER. This is then joined back to the original table and rows where the price of an item is equal to the most recent price are removed. The most recent price of the remaining data is then found for each item, again using the ROW_NUMBER technique. This is the second most recent price.